# Every measurable function is nearly continuous.

Tags: real-analysis

[image]

About the second line of the proof of theorem 4.5, why it is true that we can find such $E_n$s. My thought is that step functions are only not continuous on the boundary, so do we need to show that the measure of the boundary is zero to validate the reasoning of the second line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For fixed $n$, there is a finite partition of $E$ into measurable subsets $A_1,\dots,A_m$ such that $f_n$ is constant on each $A_i$.  Choose closed subsets $B_i\subseteq A_i$ with $\mu(A_i\setminus B_i)<\frac{1}{m2^n}$ and take $E_n=E\setminus\bigcup B_i$.  Then $f_n$ is continuous on $E\setminus E_n=\bigcup B_i$, since each $B_i$ is open in $E\setminus E_n$ (being the complement of the union of the $B_j$ for $j\neq i$) and $f_n$ is constant on each $B_i$.

Comment: Why $B_i$ is open in $E-E_n$? How do you should that the complement of it in $E-E_n$ is closed?

Comment: Its complement is a finite union of closed sets, namely the other $B_j$.

Comment: Oh, I got it, since it is finite union.